# FluentNhiberate Mapping SQLCE4 VALUES(?,?,?,?) on transaction.Save()

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I cant figure this one out...
I have tried to use FluentNhibernate with SQLCE4.. and my configs looks like this for the session:

```
    public class FluentNHibernateFactory
{
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
        .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCeDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ApplicationEntity>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetOpenSession()
    {
        return CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

and my mappings looks like this:

```
    public class ApplicationMap : ClassMap<ApplicationEntity>
{
    public ApplicationMap()
    {
        Table("Applications");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("id");
        Id(x => x.Alias).Column("alias");
        Id(x => x.Name).Column("name");
        Map(x => x.Created).Column("created");
        Map(x => x.CreatedByUser).Column("createdBy");
        Map(x => x.Updated).Column("updated");
        Map(x => x.UpdatedByUser).Column("updatedBy");
    }
}
```

and finally.. my repository looks like this..:

```
public class ApplicationRepository : IRepository<ApplicationEntity>
{

    public void Add(ApplicationEntity entity)
    {
        using (var session = FluentNHibernateFactory.GetOpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(entity);
                //TODO: Fix the add functionality
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Remove(ApplicationEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(ApplicationEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ApplicationEntity> GetAll()
    {
        using (var session = FluentNHibernateFactory.GetOpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                return session.CreateCriteria<ApplicationEntity>().List<ApplicationEntity>().AsEnumerable<ApplicationEntity>();
            }
        }
    }

    public ApplicationEntity GetById(long id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But I just can't add any objects to my database.. the entity objects that gets passed to the Add method has values for all properies and they also seems to be valid properties.. but I do however have three primary keys in the table, so might that be the problem?

the table looks like this by the way:

---

### Applications |

### Id    |  bigint   | NOT NULL | Primary key

### alias |  nvarchar(25) | NOT NULL | Primary key

### name  |  nvarchar(100) | NOT NULL | Primary key

### created | datetime | NOT NULL

### createdBy | bigint | NOT NULL

### updated | datetime | NULL

### updatedBy | bigint | NULL

Do you guys see anything wrong in here?. Im new to NHibernate so I might have been doing something really strange here..

The error im getting is:
{"could not insert: [LBi.CATT.Core.Domain.Entities.ApplicationEntity#Test][SQL: INSERT INTO Applications (created, createdBy, updated, updatedBy, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]"}

and for the inner exception:
{"Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]"}

sorry for the bad formatting of the table..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is not legal

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("id");
Id(x => x.Alias).Column("alias");
Id(x => x.Name).Column("name");
```

either use this (if Id is the primary key)

```
Id(x => x.Id)
    .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
    .UnsavedValue(0)
    .Column("id");
Map(x => x.Alias).Column("alias");
Map(x => x.Name).Column("name");
```

or this (if Id, Alias, Name together are the primary key)

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "id")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Alias, "alias")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Name, "name");
```

Comment: Did a different approach to solve this issue :).. since I already had an Id which always will be the one column to identify the post, I set that Id-column as the Id and simply just did the other columns unique.. but Ill flag your answer as the answer since I later on found out that, thats how you create a "composite-id" in NHibernate :)